# Is configuration considered a cross-cutting concern?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, configuration, cross-cutting-concerns

The title says it pretty much. 
I see sometimes people mention configuration as cross-cutting concern, but others don't. 
So I'm wondering if it is truly a cross-cutting concern.

Because I'm wondering if configuration should be injected in every level. Shouldn't every class or method access only the config it needs? Wouldn't injecting configuration in every class that needs only a small part of the config be an anti-pattern?

Comment: See also: IoC. Even with manual dependency injection, many roots are hidden in constructors or a Service Locator at similar level. As far as “what” this configuration is, is another question - and if such has defined boundaries (easier with static typing) or is a nebulous blob of configuration accessed in some generic manner.